# Configuring Jetty 9 + Spring 4 add PropertySource file

Tags: spring, jetty, jetty-9

How to add  External PropertySource file to jetty 9 jetty.xml  ?

i use spring annotation and External PropertySource file

```
  @PropertySources({
      @PropertySource(name = "arm", value = "${propertySource}")
})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

when I run the application through maven I use paramentr like propertySource:

```
mvn -DpropertySource=file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties jetty:stop jetty:run
```

Its work perfect jetty start with /etc/jetty/arm.properties config params.

How to add -DpropertySource=/etc/jetty/arm.properties like a parametn to start jetty ? hoe to configurable jetty.xml ?

I read docs 
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-xml-usage.html

and add string to jetty.xml :

```
<SystemProperty name="propertySource" default="file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties"/>
```

but this does not work, and jetty fail.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `<SystemProperty>` is to evaluate a named system property and use it in an XML file as a value for whatever thing you are attempting to configure.

There's 2 ways you can accomplish this using the jetty-distribution.

**1: Simply use the Java JVM command line to add the property**

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -DpropertySource=file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

**2: Allow the ${jetty.base} to manage the Java JVM properties**

In your `${jetty.base}` add the following 2 lines to your `start.ini`

```
--exec
-DpropertySource=file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties
```

Then you can just run Jetty normally ...

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

**Bonus: Alternate technique**

Since this is Spring, you could probably switch to using a classloader resource instead.

Run this command to enable resources classpath

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=resources
```

Then put your properties file in the new `${jetty.base}/resources`

Lastly, reference your `PropertySources` via the Spring classloader resource reference instead.

Comment: n your ${jetty.base} add the following 2 lines to your start.ini

--exec
-DpropertySource=file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties   service jetty9 start
[FAIL] Starting Jetty 9 Servlet Engine: jetty9 failed!

Answer (score 0):

```
In your ${jetty.base} add the following 2 lines to your start.ini
--exec 
-DpropertySource=file:/etc/jetty/arm.properties 

#service jetty9 start 
[FAIL] Starting Jetty 9 Servlet Engine: jetty9 failed! 


# sudo service jetty9 check
[ ok ] Checking arguments for Jetty:.
. ok 
[ ok ] PIDFILE = /var/run/jetty9.pid.
[....] JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xmx256m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/jetty9/data -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib -Djetty.home=/usr/share/jetty9 -Djetty.logs=/var/log/jetty9 -Djetty.state=/var/lib/jetty[ ok ty.state.
[ ok ] JAVA = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.
[ ok ] JETTY_USER = jetty.
[ ok ] ARGUMENTS =.
[ ok ] Jetty 9 Servlet Engine is running with pid 23749.
```

**solution 2**

add to start.ini line --add-to-start=resourcesc

```
# sudo service jetty9 start
[warn] Starting Jetty 9 Servlet Engine: jetty9[....] /var/run/jetty9.pid exists, but jetty was not running. Ignoring /var/run/jetty9.pid ... (warning).
 failed!
```

**Where can I see the log** ?